# Fetch records between 0 and 100 without using between in mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, dbal

I want to fetch records between 0 and 100 in mysql without using `between` clause, because when I use a query like this

```
$this->db->having('distance between 0 and 100');
```

I get an error like:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `between0 and 100`

You'll see the `0` does not get a space before it, so that the statement produces an error.

How to make sure a space remains before the 0 or else: how to exclude `between` in a query

Comment: The `HAVING` token is for aggregated results only. Do you aggregate? What framework do you use, doesn't it do real mysql statements?

Comment: is $this->db your db driver, or a adapter class or a framework? This is really guessing

Comment: codeigniter3....

Comment: try `$this->db->where('distance between 0 and 100')`

Comment: Post the entire code that builds the query.

Comment: no its not working @trincot

Comment: try `$this->db->having('(distance>0 and distance<=100) or (distance>=0 and distance<100)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple ways to get this

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("table-name");
$this->db->where('distance >=', 0)
$this->db->where('distance <=', 100);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

OR

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table-name WHERE distance <= 100 AND distance >= 0");
return $query->result(); //or $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
$this->db
    ->group_start()
        ->where('distance <=', 100)
        ->where('distance >=', 0)
    ->group_end();
```

its perfectly fine if you remove the group statements in case you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$this->db->having(array('distance >=' => 0, 'distance <=' => 100));
// Produces: HAVING distance => 0, distance <= 100
```